# How to make sure that my data does not get overwritten when user inputs new ones? [C Structures & Files]

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to create a program that can contain multiple playlists with multiple songs. My problem is that each playlist seem to only be able to contain one song. When the user inputs a new song, the previous one gets overwritten. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read lines and then `sscanf()` to parse the line. `fgets()` takes a max length so no overflow possible.

Comment: Why not refer to the song by a pointer inside the playlist, instead of copying it in completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `songs` is an array. When you do `songs->title` you access the title of the first element of the array.

You shall have an index to keep track of the set song. The field `song_count` seems to be here for that purpose.

```
void addSongToPlaylist(struct playlist *playlists, int index){
    int i, choice;

    printf("THE PLAYLISTS AVAILABLE ARE:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        printf("\t[%d] %s\n", i, playlists[i].name);
    }

    printf("\nEnter playlist number: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    printf("\nEnter song title: ");
    scanf("%s", playlists[choice].songs[playlists[choice].song_count].title); 
    printf("Enter song artist: ");
    scanf("%s", playlists[choice].songs[playlists[choice].song_count].artist); 
    printf("Enter song album: ");
    scanf("%s", playlists[choice].songs[playlists[choice].song_count].album); 

    // Increment sound_count for next time
    playlists[choice].song_count++;

    printf("Succesfully added song to playlist!\n");
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this still didn't work for my code :( . It ended up not retaining any of the input at all, though the song_count is being incremented just fine.

Comment: Nothing is written into the structure ? Could you add the initialization of the `playlists` variable and the call to `addSongToPlaylist` ?

Comment: I just edited my question to include the main function where I initialize playlists variable and call addSongToPlaylist. But these are basically the lines that I used: 
struct playlist playlists[50];
addSongToPlaylist(playlists, index);

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I don't see any issue with that part. How do you know that the input is not retained ? If you add a `printf("title added: %s\n", playlists[choice].songs[playlists[choice].song_count].title)` write after the scanf, is there no output ?

Comment: Yes, there's no output. Btw, sorry to keep bugging you, I'm just really stuck on this problem and can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: That's weird. If you look up the manual of `scanf` you can notice that it returns an int. This value is the status of the operation. To check it, may you add the following include `#include <errno.h>` and after each `scanf` add `perror("scanf return: ");` ?